# My CV is suddenly hidden from employers

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, jobs

I logged into Careers today and noticed that my CV was hidden from employers.

I don't recall making any changes to my settings recently, the only action I've taken with Careers recently is to reply "No thanks" (or possibly "No longer looking") to a message from an employer.

Should replying "No longer looking" have changed my overall CV status? I didn't intend to make my CV un-searchable by employers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should replying "No longer looking" have changed my overall CV status?

Replying "no longer looking" tells us you.. are no longer looking, and turns off employer searchability on your CV.

So if you don't want this, just decline employer requests instead.

Comment: Plus the employer is likely to turn right around and do the same search again, and after having you respond "No longer looking" but still showing up in the results is annoying and confusing.  Don't use "no longer looking" when you really mean "no thanks."

Comment: Thanks. I just didn't realize that my response to an individual response would affect the status of my overall CV. It makes sense, just was not expected.

Comment: Perhaps a note on that option, "Selecting this option will un-file your CV so it no longer appears in employer searches."

Answer (score 11):

"No longer looking" does mean that you are no longer looking for a job, in which case it is `status-bydesign` to hide your CV after selecting that option.

If you are "no longer looking", why waste employers' time by listing the CV of someone not interested in a job anyway?

Comment: My response was really "No longer looking in your area", but this makes sense anyway.

Comment: Maybe careers needs a `No Longer Looking AT YOU` response button?